# How can I use the same generic type in multiple methods in a non-generic static class

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a static (thus non-generic) class which contains a method called

```
Initialize<T>();
```

This method will be called on startup and will define the generic type of the class. So I want to be able to set the return value of other methods to the same type as T.

The result should look like something like this:

```
public static class ServiceClientBase
{
    private static IRestClient _client;

    public static void Initialize<T>(T restClient)
    {
        _client = restClient;
    }

    public static T GetClient()
    {
        return (T)_client;
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesnt work because GetClient() doesnt know type T. But T from GetClient should be equal to T from Initialize.

Is there a way to accomplish this? If not, is there a useful pattern, to accomplish something similar?

Thanks alot!

Comment: As all your parameters seem to be assigned to `_client` which is of type `IRestClient`, you probably need some generic sonstraint: `where T: I RestClient`?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you called `Initialize<Foo>` and then `Initialize<Bar>`? It sounds like you want a generic class really - and static classes *can* be generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've made an incorrect assumption here:

> I am trying to create a static (thus non-generic) class

Static classes can absolutely be generic. I believe you just want:

```
public static class ServiceClientBase<T> where T : IRestClient
{
    private static T _client;

    public static void Initialize(T restClient)
    {
        _client = restClient;
    }

    public static T GetClient()
    {
        return _client;
    }
}
```

Then you'd use:

```
ServiceClientBase<Foo>.Initialize(client);
...
Foo foo = ServiceClientBase<Foo>.GetClient();
```

Your non-generic version would cause problems if you called `Initialize` twice with two different types - you've only got a single field. With the generic type, you've got a field per constructed type.

As a side-note, `ServiceClientBase` is a very odd name for a static class - it sounds like it should be the *base* class for something, but nothing can derive from a static class.

Secondly, this is just a glorified singleton pattern. I'd encourage you to investigate dependency injection instead as a better way of handling this sort of thing.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Yup, I hadn't noticed it before - thanks for that. (Although admittedly the constraint isn't required when the field is of type T :)

Comment: I have used DI to solve my problem. Thanks für the tip